# Use self to refer to highest class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

How do I use `self` to go up two classes? For example, I have the following code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    class Current
        self.state = true
    end
end
```

I need `self.state` to refer to the Project's state, not the Current's state. How do I use `self` to refer to `Project`?

UPDATE:  After several comments, I am rephrasing the code to make the question easier:

I need to refer to the current instance of Project from within the Current class.  From my understanding, the code above is incorrect and this should be how to do it:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    class Current
        change_state
    end

    def change_state
        self.state = true
    end
end
```

However, when I use this code, I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `change_state' for #<current:0x007fd13953ee60>
```

My question is essentially the same, how do I refer to the current instance of Project from within Current?

Comment: You have no control over `self` - it is what it is based on the context you're in. You can't assign to it. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I need to somehow access the instance of project.  I need a way, like self would do with the class its in, to refer two classes up.

Comment: After reading everyone's comments, I have updated the question to better reflect the problem I am having

Comment: Question: Is Current really supposed to be a generic Object subclass, or is it meant to be a subclass of Project? As written, these two classes are unrelated except that one is used as a namespace for the other.

Comment: It's a subclass of Project.

Comment: Oh i understand your question.  In my actual code, current is called state machine. I'll change the content now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're putting a class inside another one like this:

```
class Alice < ActiveRecord::Base
  class Bob
  end
end
```

When you do this, Bob isn't a subclass of Alice *or* ActiveRecord::Base. Bob is just a subclass of Object. The only relationship between Alice and Bob is that you access Bob by writing Alice::Bob. To make Bob a subclass of Alice, you have to define it like this:

```
class Bob < Alice
end
```

If you do it that way, Bob will inherit Alice's methods. You can still put it inside Alice's namespace if you want, but the important thing is that you use `class Bob < Alice` so Ruby knows you want Bob to be Alice's subclass rather than just an unrelated class hanging out in her namespace.

Comment: But that will refer to the whole model.  Self refers to the model and then I would need to define the instance.  I need a way, like self would do with the class its in, to refer two classes up.

Comment: @Philip7899: I don't understand what you're saying. In your example, `self` *is* the class. Are you saying this is actually supposed to be in an instance method? What is it you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong, but when I use 'self' within a model, aren't i referring to the current instance of the class?  I need to refer to the current instance of Project from within Current.

Comment: @Philip7899: When you use `self` in the context of a class definition, it refers to the class. When you use it in the context of an instance method, it refers to an instance. The example you gave was outside of any instance method, so `self` would refer to the class itself. I think it would help if you just asked about what you were trying to accomplish instead of asking about the specific *way* you want to accomplish it (e.g. "I want to have a collection that maps names with objects" rather than "I want to port PHP's associative arrays to Ruby").

Comment: Chuck, good call.  I edited my question accordingly.  Thank you.

Comment: @Philip7899 I would extremely suggest you reading a little bit about ```self```. It seems confusing, but once you grasp the fundamentals, it is indeed really easy.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not properly formed. The error you are getting is coming from the Ruby interpreter when it first executes the body of the outer `class` as part of defining that class and, as part of that, executes the body of the inner class as part of defining *that* class. `change_state` is not defined at that point, so that class definition(s) fail.

Here's a simple example:

```
class Foo
  puts 1
  class Bar
    baz
  end
  puts 2
end
```

If you execute this in irb, you'll see that `1` is printed out and then you get the error about `baz` being undefined. Neither `Foo` nor `Bar` have been invoked at this point. Those classes are in the process of being defined, so they can't be instantiated.

Comment: That is not right. Ruby doesn't do that kind of type checking. You won't get an error until the message send actually fails.

Comment: Well, I didn't mean to imply any type checking, but you're right that the error doesn't occur after the lexical parsing of `check_state`, but rather after the closing `end`s. Thanks for pointing out the error.